# selecting rows from sql server where a casting issue occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, casting, types

i was just wondering if anyone knows how to select rows where a specified column will come under a casting issue.

ie.

> SELECT * FROM ThisTable t
>
> WHERE 0 <> ( select cast(t.value as
>   datetime) )

the 'select cast(t.value as datetime)' would ideally return the result of @@error
to indicate the casting issue has occurred.

does anyone have any idea, because im bloody stumped.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ThisTable t

WHERE ISDATE(t.value) = 1 -- or 0 for NOT a datetime valaue
```

[ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) is your friend, if I understand correctly...

Comment: haha yeah a coworker came over to me 20mins later and pulled it out of his bag of tricks... had no idea isdate even existed!! goes to show you learn something new everyday ;)

thankyou for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a solution to avoid errors when converting varchar to datetime in SQL server.

I have a varchar column containing dates with inconsistent entries like DD.MM.YYYY or MM.YYYY. With a simple cast, the query works correctly only until it encounters a record with the former format, which causes a cast error and interrupts the query. Using your suggestion, I can easily catch the MM.YYYY values and set them to null, which is exactly what I want.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(contract_date) = 1 
            THEN CAST(contract_date AS datetime)
            ELSE NULL
       END converted_dates
FROM contracts
```

"01.01.2009" gets successfully converted to "01.01.2009 00:00:00" whereas "01.2009" is returned as NULL.